# getMap not Functioning- Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm having trouble with the setMap function with Google Maps API v3 when trying to draw a polyline between two coords.

I've checked to see where about the code is failing with an `alert()` and it seems to be at the setMap function. Does anyone have any ideas why this would be happening?

```
function showPosition(position)
  {
  lat=position.coords.latitude;
  lon=position.coords.longitude;
  speed= position.coords.speed;
  altitude = position.coords.altitude;


  latlon=new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon, speed, altitude)
  mapholder=document.getElementById('mapholder')
  mapholder.style.height='250px';
  mapholder.style.width='500px';

  var myOptions={
  center:latlon,zoom:14,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  mapTypeControl:false,
  navigationControlOptions:{style:google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL}
  };
  var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapholder"),myOptions);
  var marker=new google.maps.Marker({position:latlon,map:map,title:"You are here!"});


    x.innerHTML="Latitude: " + lat + " Long: " + lon;
  mapRoute();

  }

function mapRoute(showPosition, position){


var routeCoordinates = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(53.379763, -1.4658453999999999),
    new google.maps.LatLng(21.291982, -157.821856)   
  ];



  var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: routeCoordinates,
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });


 flightPath.setMap(map);


}
```

Thanks in advance,
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a scope problem

the `var map` is defined inside of `function showPosition(position)` instead of being a global variable

add a `var map;` above any function call and remove the `var` from `var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapholder"),myOptions);`

then you should be able to access `map` inside `flightPath.setMap(map);`